# Block same instance of a program for running again

Tags: c, linux

I am implementing a library (Linux) and I created some functions to block new instances of a running program and I was wonder if there are some better improvements for it.

Here is a program which describes what I am trying:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define SECONDS 20

static char *program_path = NULL;

char *my_strtok         ( char *const msg, const char *const ch );
void block_new_instance ( const char *const instance );
void clean_instance     ( void );

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if ( argc != 1 )
    {
        printf( "\n\t*** Arguments are NOT allowed. ***\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    block_new_instance( argv[ 0 ]  );
    sleep( SECONDS );
}

void block_new_instance( const char *const instance )
{
    char prog_name[ strlen( instance ) + 1 ];
    memset( prog_name, '\0', sizeof( prog_name ) );
    strcpy( prog_name, instance );
    char *buffer = my_strtok( prog_name, "/" );
    struct flock file_lock;
    char *dir = getenv( "HOME" );

    if ( dir == NULL || dir[0] != '/' )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Wrong Directory, getenv(): %s (%d)\n", strerror( errno ), errno );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    program_path = calloc( sizeof ( *program_path ), strlen( dir ) + ( strlen( buffer )  + sizeof ( "/" ) ) );
    if ( program_path == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Error, malloc()\n" );
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    memcpy( program_path, dir, strlen( dir ) );
    memcpy( program_path + strlen( dir ), "/", sizeof( "/") );
    memcpy( program_path + ( strlen( dir ) + strlen( "/" ) ), buffer, strlen( buffer ) );

    int file_desk = open( program_path, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0600 );
    if ( file_desk < 0 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "open: %s (%d)\n", strerror( errno ), errno );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    file_lock.l_start   = 0;
    file_lock.l_len     = 0;
    file_lock.l_type    = F_WRLCK;
    file_lock.l_whence  = SEEK_SET;

    if ( fcntl( file_desk, F_SETLK, &file_lock ) < 0 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "%s is already running\n", buffer );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    atexit( clean_instance );
}

char *my_strtok( char *const msg, const char *const ch )
{
    char *ret = NULL;
    char *tmp = strtok( msg, ch );
    while ( tmp != NULL )
    {
        ret = tmp;
        tmp = strtok( NULL, ch );
    }

    if ( ret == NULL )
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    return ret;
}

void clean_instance( void )
{
    unlink ( program_path );
    free   ( program_path );
}
```

Possible Outputs are:

> *** Arguments are NOT allowed. **

or:

> Program is already running

I would like to know which improvements are needed?

Comment: When/Why would you use this? More context would help with figuring out possible (unwanted) side-effects.

Comment: The usual motivation is for daemons - but most platforms have libraries or utility programs to manage pidfiles for you (in the right place) so you don't have to roll your own.  For example, Debian has `start-stop-daemon` (and even if you don't use it, you can follow its conventions)

Comment: @Mast there is about an application which it will be compiled/installed in `&HOME` and I need to prevent it for running more instance of the same program on that Machine.

Comment: Please read ["*What should I do when someone answers my question?*"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Three calls to `memcpy` seem to emulate `sprintf(program_path, "%s/%s", dir, buffer);`
- `my_strtok` is a not very clean substitute for `dirname`.
- The lock file is always created in the home directory, and only accounts for the base name of the executable. It means that `/usr/foo` would block `/opt/foo`.
- The locker does not account for the links (again, it only cares about the base name of the executable). Different names may refer to the physically same file; invocations via links would not lock each other out.
- A callback registered with `atexit` is only guaranteed to be called if the program exits normally. If the program is terminated by the signal, the lock file would not be removed.

Comment: Ar you suggesting that I change `char *dir = getenv( "PATH" );` to `const char *dir = "/tmp";` ?

Comment: `my_strtok is a not very clean substitute for dirname.` I was thinking to call `extern char *__progname` but I am not familiar with it. Does Apply to all Linux environments or only some of them?

Comment: `A callback registered with atexit is only guaranteed to be called if the program exits normally. ` - I updated my Question and added  a function called `catch_ctrl_c_and_exit` and used as argument for SIGNAL `signal( SIGINT, catch_ctrl_c_and_exit );` and I also changed `char *dir = getenv( "PATH" );`   to `const char *dir = "/tmp";`

Comment: Using  `CTRL+C` or `killall -9 PID` seems to remove the file from `/tmp/`. Do I need some more features?